# how to stop OracleRemExecServiceV2 from cmd?

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, command-line

I have Oracle 12c running on Windows 7.

When I look at the Oracle's specific services (Control Panel\System and Security\Administrative Tools\Services), I have the following 6 services:

[image]

So far, everything is normal. I can even start or stop every service by double clicking on it, and then clicking the Start/Stop button.
However, for convenience, I want to create a .bat file with commands to open/close all the services. I run in command prompt commands such as `net stop  [service]`, and they all work fine except for OracleRemExecServiceV2.

[image]

As you can see, I get System error 5 - access is denied. How can I solve this problem?

**UPDATE**:

i ran cmd as admin. Please see the below screenshot. In the Services window, OracleRemExecServiceV2 remains in the 'Starting' state for a long time, without changing to 'Started'.

[image]

One more thing: i double clicked the OracleRemExecServiceV2 and, in the General tab, i noticed that the Path was something like C:... (i cannot remember), while the database is installed on D, and all the other five Oracle services have the Path beginning with D:\app\OracleHomeUser\product\12.1.0\dbhome\BIN. So i changed it accordingly, to  point to RemoteExecService.exe in the BIN folder in the D directory. Is it ok what I did? otherwise, what would be the normal value for the path of this service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TASKKILL /IM RemoteExecService.exe /F`

It's placed in `C:\Temp\2\\oraremservicev2\RemoteExecService.exe`.

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

`[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\OracleRemExecServiceV2]`

Comment: in my case, `RemoteExecService.exe` is placed under `OracleHomeUser\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\BIN` ; however, the command `taskkill` worked just fine

Answer (score 0):

Use a command line started with administrator privileges.

[image]

Comment: I tried what you said, and I have appended a printscreen to the question